# Preservation of angle by multiplication of conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I need help to understand a certain part of a proof (b). I have problems to understand the sentence and its conclusion, "Since B and M' depend continiously on $\beta$ only one of the two values $\pm\alpha$ can occur" why does $B$ and $M'$ depend continiously on $\beta$ and why does it follow that either $\alpha$ or $-\alpha$?

Source [Algebra Artin 2nd edition](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Eliweiyu/documents/Algebra,%20Second%20Edition,%20Michael%20Artin.pdf) page 137/138
[image: arr]

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Artin's phrasing of the argument:

Let $B$ be a rotation about some pole $p$, and let $B$ have rotation angle $\beta$. Fix $p$ and let $\beta$ vary. Each entry of the matrix $B$ is some continuous function of $\beta$ (which you can explicitly write out if you want to), and thus so is each entry of $M'=BMB^t$.

We claim that the angle of rotation $\alpha'$ of $M'$ is also a continuous function of $\beta$. This is both somewhat obvious (since $M'$ has entries that vary continuously in $\beta$) and somewhat delicate -- essentially we can imagine $M'$ "moving around $SO_3$" (with respect to some standard topology), in which case the statement that the angle of rotation of $M'$ (at least away from the identity transformation) is continuous in $M'$. I'm sure it's also possible to write out a completely algebraic proof of this fact by explicitly finding the angle of rotation in terms of the entries of $M'$, but doing that doesn't seem particularly useful.

So, $\alpha'$ is a continuous function of $\beta$, but on the other hand we know that $\alpha'\in\{\alpha,-\alpha\}$. So, we can't have $\alpha'(\beta_1)=\alpha$ and $\alpha'(\beta_2)=-\alpha$ for some $(\beta_1,\beta_2)$, as otherwise $\alpha'$ would have to jump from $\alpha$ to $-\alpha$, which can't happen. So, if $\alpha'(\beta)=\alpha$ for *some* $\beta$, it is $\alpha$ for **all** $\beta$. It's not hard to see that $\alpha'(0)=\alpha$, which gives the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot the details about my question and the background but it helped me a lot nevertheless. Maybe I will study your answer more in detail later and make a comment. That's why I have not accepted it yet but I will still give you the points